# i have insert all data in input every time i want update some value

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

i new using Angular and nodejs with mongodb 
my problem its i have to insert all data again every time i want update my data
the value appers correctly in my form but if not insert again the all data the input the data not change its update null
my code
my editcliente.html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:34px;height:34px"  value="{{id}}" readonly>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Name"> Name of Customor</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="Name"  value="{{name}}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Address"> Address</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="Address" value="{{address}}">
    </div>
```

my cliente.ts

```
registerUser(id:any){
let name = this.registerForm.value.Name;
let address= this.registerForm.value.Address;
let telephone = this.registerForm.value.Telephone;
let postalcode = this.registerForm.value.PostalCode;
let email = this.registerForm.value.email;

 this.myfirstService.getupdate(id,name,address,telephone,postalcode,email).subscribe(data=>{
       if(data.success){
        console.log("deu")
       }
       else{
         console.log(" nao deu")
       }

  })

}

app.post('/api/updateCliente',async (req,res)=>{
  const {id,name,address,telephone,postalcode,email}= req.body
  console.log(id,name,address,telephone,postalcode,email);
  const resp = await Clientes.findOne({_id:id})

  if(!resp){
res.json({
  sucess:false,
message:'invalid cliente'
});
return
}
else{
await Clientes.updateOne({_id:id},{$set:{
  name:name,
  address:address,
  email:email,
  telephone:telephone,
  postalcode:postalcode}})
res.json({
  sucess:true
});

}
})
```

how i fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

`updateOne` works on a retrieved document, i.e. your `resp` that was returned by `Clientes.findOne`.

Try something like:

```
resp.updateOne({
  name:name,
  address:address,
  email:email,
  telephone:telephone,
  postalcode:postalcode})
```

Comment: dont work its givem-me value empty in my form  i put this code console.log(id,name,address,telephone,postalcode,email) and its this  result 1 '' '' '' '' ''

Comment: the problem cam be in this code constructor(private myfirstService:ClientesService,private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        name: new FormControl([Validators.required]),
        address: new FormControl([Validators.required]),
              bi: new FormControl([Validators.required]),
                nif: new FormControl([Validators.required]),
                  telephone: new FormControl([Validators.required]),
                    postalcode: new FormControl([Validators.required]),
        }); }